# How to clean Addresses on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently working with a large data set in google sheets and i'm working with property addresses. Since the data i get is from different providers it has a different formatting for every address:

1 NINEMILE POINT RD SEVILLE

2 PARKVIEW DR SARASOTA, FL, 34243

3 28TH ST S

4 ROSELAND DRIVE

I must be able to have a City, State, and Zip code for each entry plus the address for my project. I am currently trying to solve this problem by copying and pasting each incomplete address into google and getting the default search address result. Is there anyway to do this automatically in the google sheet? This will take me hours to do many addresses by hand. Thank you in advance